# How does a tf.train.Int64LIst hold dtype unint64?

Tags: python, tensorflow

From the tensorflow docs for [TFRecords and tf.Example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord), it states on the topic of `tf.train.Feature`:

> The `tf.train.Feature` message type can accept one of the following three types (See the .proto file for reference). Most other generic types can be coerced into one of these:
>
> `tf.train.BytesList`
>
> ...
>
> `tf.train.FloatList`
>
> ...
>
> `tf.train.Int64List` (the following types can be coerced)
>
> - bool
> - enum
> - int32
> - uint32
> - int64
> - uint64

How is it possible to store a `uint64` dtype into a `Int64List`?

Answer (score 0):

It says it in the documentation: Coercion.
The amount of bytes are the same. How to interpret those bytes the difference is.